# Django - Read the current's user authentication backend class

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-contrib

I am using a custom authentication backend with Django, to automatically create and login users from a legacy system. My `Backend` class is this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from sfi.models import Employee
import base64, hashlib

class SFIUserBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if not username or not password:
            return

        digest = base64.standard_b64encode(hashlib.md5(password).digest())
        user = None
        try:
            employee = Employee.objects.get(login=username, passwd=digest)
            user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
            if created:
                # setting attributes
                user.first_name = employee.names[:30]
                user.last_name = employee.surnames[:30]
                user.is_staff = True
                user.save()
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return user
```

So far, it works fine. However, I need to read the backend class of the currently logged user in a template.

Using `request.user.backend` says that `user` does not have the attribute backend... and I cannot read it from the session (using `request.session._auth_user_backend`) because the Django template system complains that "Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores".

I am using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` to allow users login. What am I missing?

Comment: btw this authentication scheme looks really unsecure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In django, after a login how can I detect which auth backend authenticated the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272414/in-django-after-a-login-how-can-i-detect-which-auth-backend-authenticated-the-u)

Answer (score 2):

The `backend` attribute is added to the `user` object when the user authenticates using the  `django.contrib.auth.authenticate(username='foo',password='bar')` function.

This function in turn calls all of the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` you have specified in your `settings.py` file, until it is able to authenticate successfully using one of them.

If your users are "logged in" but don't have a `backend` attribute that probably means you're not properly authenticating them. Maybe you're calling your `SFIUserBackend.authenticate` function directly, when you should be calling the `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` function?

Check out these [custom authentication docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources).

Comment: `user.backend` is only available in the login request.

Answer (score 0):

You should read it in the the view and send an appropriate human form of that class name as the message.

Answer (score 0):

While `authenticate()` adds the `user.backend` attribute and `login()` saves it in the session, for some reason `get_user()` does not add it back to the user. I have [submitted a patch](https://github.com/django/django/pull/9936).

Therefore, in order to access it in another request, you need `request.session[django.contrib.auth.BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]`.

You can also write a custom tag or add it to your context (under whatever name you want) for ease of use.