# In Django, after a login how can I detect which auth backend authenticated the user?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to distinguish between a couple of Django authentication backends (which are external packages and I preferably don't want to modify them) in my views. `django.contrib.auth` docs says auth backends (`settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`) will be tried in order and the first that does authenticate, will return and set `request.user` and if any raises an exception, authentication is refused. But it does not say how can I distinguish between requests depending on which backend has authenticated the user.

Is this possible? and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Read the current's user authentication backend class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025367/django-read-the-currents-user-authentication-backend-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in [Django docs for authentication backends settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends):

> Once a user has authenticated, Django stores which backend was used to authenticate the user in the user’s session, and re-uses the same backend for the duration of that session whenever access to the currently authenticated user is needed. This effectively means that authentication sources are cached on a per-session basis

Actually, this information is stored when function `login(request, user, backend=None)` is used (see [`django.contrib.auth.__init__.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login)). After user has been authenticated, following session information are stored:

```
SESSION_KEY = '_auth_user_id'
BACKEND_SESSION_KEY = '_auth_user_backend'
HASH_SESSION_KEY = '_auth_user_hash'
# [...]
request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = backend
request.session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = session_auth_hash
```

So, you should check current request's session for key `BACKEND_SESSION_KEY` to find the backend used to authenticate user.

Comment: Thanks, but while this is supposed to generally work, It's worth to know that if you don't want to put an auth backend in `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` **and** the backend has not implemented passing the optional `backend` param to call to `django.contrib.auth.login()` (which lots of them dont), then this would not work. In this case I had to resort to receiving login and logout signals that are hopefully sent and are sent correctly (with passing `request` object) from auth backends and setting a suitable flag in `request.session` in signal handler manually.

Comment: You should use `django.contrib.auth.BACKEND_SESSION_KEY`, not `'_auth_user_backend'` directly.